# Search JSON result

Tags: php, json

Trying to build an automatic currency conversion based on IP.

I can get the 2 digit country code easy enough ..

```
 $remote_IP_url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $remote_user_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_IP_url));
 if ( $remote_user_data->status == 'success' ) {
 $user_country = $remote_user_data->countryCode;
 // do your check and get the currency code w.r.t. the $user_country in the previous line
 echo $user_country;
```

But I need to convert it to 3 digit for google to work.

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   // 2. set the options, including the url
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?                     a=".$price."&from=USD&to=".$convertto." ");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   // 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   // 4. free up the curl handle
   curl_close($ch);
  $data = explode('<div id=currency_converter_result>',$output);
  $data2 = explode('<div id=currency_converter_result>',$data['1']);
  $data3=explode('<span>',$data2['0']);
  $data4=explode('</span>',$data3['1']);
  $data5=explode(' ',$data4['0']);
  return $data5[0];
```

I have found a source for country codes to currency codes at http://country.io/currency.json which gives the result as ..

```
  {
       "BD": "BDT",
       "BE": "EUR",
       "BF": "XOF",
       "BG": "BGN",
       "BA": "BAM",
       "BB": "BBD",
       "WF": "XPF",
       "BL": "EUR",
       "BM": "BMD",
       "BN": "BND",
       "BO": "BOB",
```

...

But I am not sure as to how to search the JSON for the required country code an pick off the currency code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `$user_country` variable does contain the country code, you can fetch the JSON from country.io, convert it to an array, and check if the country code key exists in that array.

It'll probably be a better idea to convert the JSON from country.io to an array and put it within your PHP file instead of fetching it and converting it to an array on the fly each request.

```
<?php
$currency = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://country.io/currency.json'), true );

if( isset( $currency[ $user_country ] ) )
{
    $currency_code = $currency[ $user_country ];
}
else
{
    $currency_code = 'Not found';
}

echo $currency_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHP 5.4:

```
$code = "BB";
$jsonString = '{"BB":"BBD","WF":"XPF"}';

$longCode = json_decode($jsonString, true)[$code];

// $longCode == "BBD"
```